# Did The Dark Tower books ever refer to psychic powers as "The Shine?"

Tags: the-dark-tower

The recent movie isn't shy about calling the Breakers' powers "The Shine." Was there any point in the books or comic books where a character refers to a psychic power as "The Shine?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In the original books, psychic powers are usually referred to as "[The Touch](http://darktower.wikia.com/wiki/The_Touch)."**

[Stephen King's website describes The Touch](http://stephenking.com/darktower/glossary.html#itemLowT):

> If a person has  the touch, he or she can read minds and/or see into the past and the future. It is similar to ESP and is half-empathy, half-telepathy.

Nowhere in the original material are psychic powers exhibited by Jake, the Breakers, or anyone else ever referred to as "The Shine". This was clearly a link/nod to [The Shining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shining_(novel)), where the young boy Danny has similar psychic powers referred to as "The Shine".

Further linking the stories, Jake's psychiatrist also happens to have a photo of the Overlook Hotel on his shelves.

[image: The Overlook Hotel]